# understanding notation for partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

I'm confused with the notation to the right of the equation. I know curly dW/curly du would be finding the partial derivative with respect to u, but the cube, and the two curly ds in the denominator and the square is throwing me off.

I'm afraid I don't understand all these notations and equivalencies as much as I'd like to. The book is a little confusing about it for some reason as well are my notes. I can't find a similar example online. Can someone please explain how to break apart this notation and understand it easily?

Comment: It means: first differentiate $W$ with respect to $v$; then differentiate the result with respect to $u$; then differentiate the result with respect to $u$ again.

Comment: It is a third partial derivative; you differentiate twice with respect to $u$ and once with respect to $v$, so three times overall.

Comment: oh i see.. and I guess the order doesn't matter since I was shown that fxy = fyx earlier

Comment: The order does make a difference in some cases, the "not nice" cases.  One aspect of the notation for partial derivatives is that it "suggests" order does not make a difference, when this is not always true, but true for cases where the function and all the derivatives are continuous.

Comment: so would I read the order in the denominator from right to left?

Comment: What I meant was that the notation used in your example leaves it ambiguous what order the derivatives should be taken in, so it "suggests" that the order will not make a difference.  Many times we adopt notations that suppress nonessential details of a calculation, and if the order of partial derivatives *will* make a difference, we must resort to a more cumbersome notation (use lots of parentheses) to make explicit in what order the derivatives are to be taken.

Comment: thanks all. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was already answered in the comments, but just to help you understand **why** the derivative is written the way it is:
$$
\frac{\partial^3 W}{\partial u^2 \partial v}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\partial}{\partial v} W
.
$$
(So $\partial u^2$ should be thought of as $(\partial u)^2$, not $\partial (u^2)$.)